# System.Collections.Generic.List <string>' does not contain a definition for 'equals'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this error and I do not understand why ..

> System.Collections.Generic.List ' does not contain a definition for 'equals'

My list is a List < List < string > >

```
<tbody>
        <tr>
            @{
                int nbItems = ViewBag.listDonnees.Count ;
                bool colore ;
                for(int cpt = 0; cpt < nbItems; cpt++)
                {
                    colore = false ;

                    if(cpt + 1 < nbItems)
                    {
                        colore = @ViewBag.listDonnees[cpt].equals("#FFFFFF") || @ViewBag.listDonnees[cpt].equals("#FFD700") || @ViewBag.listDonnees[cpt].equals("#FF6347") ;
                    }

                    if(colore)
                    {
                        <td style="background-color:@ViewBag.listDonnees[cpt+1]">@ViewBag.listDonnees[cpt]</td>
                        cpt++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@ViewBag.listDonnees[cpt]</td>
                    }
                }
            }
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

I tried to use "==" but I also have this error :

> Unable to apply operator '==' to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List ' and 'string'

Thank you for your help

Comment: Is `listDonnees` a `List<string>` or `List<List<string>>`? Maybe include a [mcve] to clear things up a bit.

Comment: List<List<string>>

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that: listDonnees[cpt] is a List, you just take the inner list of you List>. If you want to know if the inner List contains the *#FFFFFF* you need to use .Contains()

```
listDonnees[cpt].Contains("#FFFFFF")
```

Or you use a second (nested) for - loop to check every string.
By the way: You can check easier by using this:

```
colore = listDonnees[cpt].Any(s =>new List<String>() {"#FFFFFF", "#FFD700", "#FF6347"}.Contains(s));
```

So for you problem in particular:

```
int nbItems = listDonnees.Count ;
var hashCodes = new List<String>() {"#FFFFFF", "#FFD700", "#FF6347"};

for(int cpt = 0; cpt < nbItems; cpt++)
{
    string colorcode = string.Empty;
    if(cpt + 1 < nbItems)
    {
       colorcode = listDonnees[cpt].FirstOrDefault(s => hashCodes.Contains(s));
    }
    if(colorcode != string.Empty)
    {
       <td style="background-color:@colorcode">colorcode</td>
       //cpt++; See below!    
     }
     else
     {
         var str = String.Join(",", listDonnees[cpt]);
         <td>str</td>
     }
     // I Think your cpt++; needs to be here:
     cpt++;
}
```

I don't know you Model, so you might habe to change your @ViewBag accessing a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried what you proposed but it is written this in the cells of my table : System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Comment: @ValentinHrg You might update your question with **all** the relevant info.

Comment: @ValentinHrg I guess you mean the line `<td>@ViewBag.listDonnees[cpt]</td>` - what do you want to write there ? All strings in the List like comma-seperated? If so, use: `String.Join(",", listDonnees[cpt]);`

Comment: I have a query that contains hexadecimal codes and when there is a hexadecimal code I want to apply a background-color to the previous data in my table

Comment: I can not do it :( I'ts possible to have the double loop please ?

Comment: @ValentinHrg okay, I understand that, but what I needed to know is, which line is writing _System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]_ into your page. As i guessed above, I think it must be the line in else clause. Have you tried what I suggested above?

Comment: It is written in each cell :/ I have tried the suggested above, I only replaced    colore = @ViewBag.listDonnees[cpt].equals("#FFFFFF") .....  by colore = @ViewBag.listDonnees[cpt].Contains("#FFFFFF") ..... in my if

Comment: I think the double Loop won't help you understanding what you are doing wrong... So I try again:
@ViewBag.listDonnees[cpt] <- with using this, you adress List<List<string>> at the position of cpt. Think of it as a text document. With cpt, you get the line in your document. This contains a list of words in your document. But your `style=background-color:` doesn't want a sentence, it just wants one single word, in your example it needs your hashcode. So if you want your hashcode, you need to tell which word in your sentence is the hashcode. Give me a few moments, I'll edit the answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your Edit, but I have this error in the first if : Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type.

Comment: @ValentinHrg try putting `listDonnees[cpt]` to a local variable (List<string>) then first - don't know why razor has problems with this - in a local project it just runs fine - well I don't know what your ViewBag.listDonnees look like, so this might be the problem aswell.

Comment: var mylist = ViewBag.listDonnees[cpt];
colorcode = mylist.FirstOrDefault(s => hashCodes.Contains(s)); toujours the same error :/ (s => hashCodes.Contains(s)); Is underlined in red

Comment: The error is resolved by a cast : var mylist = (IEnumerable < dynamic >) ViewBag.listDonnees[cpt];
colorcode = mylist.FirstOrDefault(s => hashCodes.Contains(s)); but the background-color is -> background-color:System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Comment: @TripleEEE I made an edit to your post. I think that is what you meant, please rollback if not.

Comment: @PatrickHofman This should be solving his issue, as I saw Valentine did open a new thread, where they just suggested the same answer on this line - hope this helps him and solves the issue